# What happened to the village in Contagion?

Tags: movie

In the movie *Contagion*, Dr. Leonora Orantes, a French member of the World Health Organisation (WHO),

> is kidnapped by a group of Chinese people trying to protect their small village. After a vaccine is finally created she is used to negotiate a handover of the vaccine.  A meetup happens and they get the vaccine.  It is later revealed that they were given a placebo.  The kidnapped woman then runs off to find out about the village.

However, I don't seem to recall if the village was ever shown again.  Do we know what happened to the village, or was that left out of the film?

Comment: I thought the same thing... lol

Comment: Is _Contagion_ a science fiction or fantasy movie?

Comment: Its not really, except that the disease itself is fictional.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield That's what I thought. Can someone move this question to movies.stackexchange then? It's offtopic here.

Comment: @AndresF. actually, no; questions can only be migrated within 60 days of being asked.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Ouch, didn't know that. Can we vote to close, then? It's still offtopic ;) Or is there some policy that old offtopic questions should be left untouched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither Dr. Orantes nor the village are shown again after she runs off from the airport.  This includes post-credit scenes (there weren't any in this movie).

> This was probably showing that the Chinese government, like its American counterpart, had priorities when it came to handing out the vaccine. And of course they don't negotiate with kidnappers. "The Chinese insisted," according to her colleague.
>
>  Since no one else appeared to be infected at the time Dr. Orantes was at the village, and the epidemic was more or less under control, I'd say they probably survive - being isolated from main urban areas and all.

Source: watched it again.

Answer (score -1):

She ran off to warn the villagers who kept her held there so they'd get the vaccine that the one they were given was a placebo and it was likely she and the villagers were vaccinated.